# How to check if a process outputs to the stderr or not?

Tags: process

Currently I'm using `make-process` and it's `stderr` argument which is a buffer.

After the process has exited I'd like to check if the `buffer-length` is zero (no error output).

This doesn't work as I get an unhelpful `Process *my-process* stderr finished`.

Is there a way to get the stderr output of a process without additional text?

(besides searching for the string literal and stripping it out which seems over-complicated).

---

To give some context, I want to treat any error output as an error for the command I'm calling, as the exit-code isn't always a reliable way of checking if an error occurred.

Comment: Note that using `cl-letf` to override `internal-default-process-sentinel` can be used to remove the extra text (`./test/lisp/net/tramp-tests.el` in emacs repo does this), although I'd rather not have to override internal functions if there is a cleaner way to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `:stderr` to `make-process`, it creates a [pipe process](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html#index-make_002dpipe_002dprocess) to filter standard error. That pipe process has its own sentinel, which isn't set explicitly so defaults to `internal-default-process-sentinel`. That function inserts the text `Process *my-process* stderr finished`. As of Emacs 26.3, I can't find a way to override this: the stderr process doesn't seem to be available from Lisp.

It does seem however that the original process sentinel runs before the pipe process sentinel. (That's from an experiment on Emacs 26.3, it may well turn out to depend on the Emacs version or on other circumstances, I haven't dug into the details.) Here's a proof-of-concept that seems to work.

```
(make-variable-buffer-local 'process-associated-stderr-buffer)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'process-associated-stderr-buffer-size)
(defun has-empty-stderr-sentinel (process event)
  (setq process-associated-stderr-buffer-size (buffer-size process-associated-stderr-buffer)))
(defun has-empty-stderr (&rest command)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((stderr-buffer (current-buffer)))
      (with-temp-buffer
    (setq process-associated-stderr-buffer stderr-buffer)
    (let ((process (make-process :name "myprocess"
                     :command command
                     :stderr stderr-buffer
                     :sentinel 'has-empty-stderr-sentinel)))
      (while (process-live-p process)
        (sit-for 0.1)))
    (= 0 process-associated-stderr-buffer-size)))))
(has-empty-stderr "ls" "/") ; → t
(has-empty-stderr "ls" "/does not exist") ; → nil
```

This is cumbersome enough that you might as well pass your own pipe process to `make-process`. Call `make-pipe-process` with a `:sentinel` argument that checks the process buffer size.

```
(defun sentinel-is-empty (process event)
  (when (equal event "finished\n")
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer process)
      (when (= 0 (buffer-size))
        …))))
(with-temp-buffer
  (let ((stderr-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (let* ((stderr-process (make-pipe-process :buffer stderr-buffer
                                              :noquery t
                                              :sentinel sentinel-is-empty)))
           (process (make-process … :stderr stderr-process)))
  …)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a good way to prevent the `Process *my-process* stderr finished` text from being written into the the output (unless you count overriding internal functions *)

The only practical way I found to do this was to handle the `stderr` output in the processes `sentinel` function.

The length of the `stderr` buffer can be checked for zero, optionally its contents read into a string.

While not ideal (as it would be nice to have a way not to append the text in the first place), all things considered it seems the most practical option.

---

* `internal-default-process-sentinel` can be overridden using `cl-letf` or advice, however it might be best to avoid this since it may be used for necessary internal operations.

NOTE: you might think that having a sentinel would override `internal-default-process-sentinel` but it doesn't, the function always runs no matter what `make-process` takes for a sentinel argument.